# Rails different versions in project folder and outside + Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, rubygems

I had big troubles with fixing RoR that works on my linux mint. Now when all seems to work fine, it doesn't. I'll describe it by c/p my terminal.

```
matth@MatijaComp /media/Data/My Documents/Sites $ rails -v
Rails 4.2.3
matth@MatijaComp /media/Data/My Documents/Sites $ cd mynewapp/
matth@MatijaComp /media/Data/My Documents/Sites/mynewapp $ rails -v
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
Rails 4.2.1
```

Well.. Outside of project folder its 4.2.3 version and inside its 4.2.1 version with warning. I was trying to remove this warning by stopping spring `spring stop` , but nothing happens..And when I try to update Rubygems it says that I have already the newest version.

Then my question is if someone would like to explain me why those versions aren't synchronized and guide me to fix this problem. Thank you!

---

**Update**

I fixed rails version, but problem still appears on this warning. when I type `gem env` it says:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/matth/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /home/matth/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/matth/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/matth/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin
     - /home/matth/bin
     - /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin
```

Now, which ever action I do with rails command in my project folder it gives me this warning. IN ADDITION, I figured out that commands even don't work. it just appears this:

```
matth@MatijaComp /media/Data/My Documents/Sites/myfourthapp $ rails generate controller demo index
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
matth@MatijaComp /media/Data/My Documents/Sites/myfourthapp $
```

I have "fixed" problem temporary by commenting `gem 'spring'` in Gemfile. But it is not the way out of this problem.

Comment: are you working with rvm? do you have .ruby-version into you folder?

Comment: I'm not using rvm, but I'm using rbenv. And I do not have .ruby-version into my project folder. BUT I used it before and maybe I messed up something with path. You know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Rails is just a gem. Among with other gems in the project, it is managed by [bundler](http://bundler.io) on a per-project basis.

If you need to change gem version, just specify it in the Gemfile, and run `bundle install`.

Comment: yes, but why this warning appears? when i enter `gem env` it says: 
`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]` ....